# Что из себя представляет цифровое изображение?

Tags: node.js, запрос, get, изображения

Пишу приложение на node.js. Появилась необходимость скачать со своего сервера картинку.
Раньше я скачивал текстовые файлы (с расширением .js, .html...), но изображения - никогда.

Решил попробовать скачать так же, как и текст:

```
https.get('https://domenname.com/image.png', (response) => {
    var result = '';
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        result += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', () => {
        fs.writeFile('downloaded.png', result, () => {});
    });
});
```

Но нет, картинка не открывается. Пришлось лезть в гугл, почитал про `response.pipe()`, попробовал, работает.

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream('downloaded.png');
https.get('https://domenname.com/image.png', (response) => {
    response.pipe(file);
});
```

И чем же тогда является цифровое изображение? Как работает `pipe()`? Почему изображение (как и аудио, как и видео) нельзя получить при помощи первого способа?

Comment: Потому что node.js по умолчанию пытается декодировать байты в символы, но типичное изображение нельзя представить в виде набора символов, и всё ломается

Comment: Или как вариант: байты всё-таки кое-как декодируются в символы, но при записи файла символы кодируются в байты неправильно (с использованием другой кодировки), и из-за этого файл тоже может получиться битым

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740659/downloading-images-with-node-js